# JFrame setTitle not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jfilechooser, titlebar

Not sure why this is occurring, but when I try to change the title on my JFrame it's not updating. The JFrame is static, and I call it by saying:

```
Assets.frame.setTitle("test");
```

I have one block of code in which I pass in a file's name, and it seems to work, as when I print out `Assets.frame.getTitle()`, it prints out what I want the title to be. But on the actual JFrame it doesn't change the title. I call the method in other parts of my program too, and it seems to work there. Is there some special character that could cause the method to not update the actual frame that I don't know about?

**Edit:**

What I'm trying to do (open a file)

```
public static void open() {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    int result = chooser.showOpenDialog(Assets.frame);
    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        MyFile myFile = new MyFile(chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());
        Main.setTitle(Constants.current_file.getName().substring(0, mapFile.getName().indexOf('.')));
    }
}
```

and the Main.setTitle() method is:

```
public static void setTitle(String title) {
    Assets.frame.setTitle(title + " - " + "My Program");
}
```

The frame is defined and instantiated near program execution, and the open method is called when a JButton is pressed. This is the only JFrame I have in the project, and it is in use until the program is exited.

I don't know how reproducible it is, as it works when I run another similar method that has a call to Main.setTitle() too. It's just this one instance where it doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is, the frame you are changing is not the one that's one the screen. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: `The JFrame is static,` - indication of a bad design. Generally you should not be using static variables to reference components in your application.

Comment: `static`, `static` everywhere. `static` is not a cross object communication mechanism and you should limit how you use it. Instead, pass a reference of the objects you need to the other classes, maybe utilising `interfaces` to limit the effect of change those other classes can actual inflict

Comment: Honestly, I just used static because I could Tools.open() and Tools.save() in other classes, I didn't know it had an effect on my program. Any reason why having static methods for updating components is a bad idea?

Comment: I'll try restructuring my program to not include so many static components, because I think all of them are. Thanks guys for your suggestions, I'll look into how to properly structure swing components

Comment: If you happen to be on Linux running Gnome, be aware that the (default) GTK look-and-feel implementation is hot garbage.  It is now mid-2022 and this has been broken for an entire decade - they refuse to fix it on principle.   This is but one of the many exciting symptoms of whatever disease this is.  Just don't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm trying to do (open a file)

Then maybe take a look at the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) as a starting point. It will show you how to better structure your program so you don't need static variables and methods everywhere. You can download the demo code and play with it and then modify it for your needs.

Then in your logic if you want to update the title of your frame then you can use the `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(...)` method to get the frame your components are added to.

The code you posted still doesn't help us understand the design of your code or the context of how the method is invoked, so why can't give you a specific answer to your problem. That is why you were asked to provide a "runnable example". But I suggest you restructure you program first.

Comment: I'll look into the SwingUtilities methods, I had no idea that static components were a bad idea. Thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are updating the UI only from the **event dispatch thread**. See `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: Nice advice, completely pointless to the question, it will have no effect over the outcome

Comment: Can I surround the Assets.frame.setTitle() with SwingUtilities.invokeLater()?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, you are saying it will have no effect as long as open() is being called from the button action event, right?  i.e. already in event dispatch thread.

Comment: Actually, I'm saying your can (but shouldn't) call `setTitle` out side of the EDT, while it's good advice, unless the OP has some thread race condition going on, it won't make any difference. I'm also "suggesting" that there simply isn't enough context to the question to make a firm recommendation (at least to the course of the problem)

Comment: Also, if anyone wants to know how I solved this (sorry for more static), I changed the setTitle() method to ((JFrame) (SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(Constants.main))).setTitle(title + " - " + "My Program");